# unresolved external symbol (still occurring)

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2013

When building my application in Debug mode: The build works.  The application works.
When building my application in Release mode, I get the following error message

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetClassNameA@12 referenced in function _eachWindow@8
```

All implementation files of my application have a `.c` extension; that however doesn't mean I would know which compiler is used by visual studio.

From the documentation of GetClassNameA I can see that a library `User32.lib` is required.  I have found a library with that name in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib>

I have added that directory to the property pages:

> Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library
>   Directories

but that did not help.  I am still receiving that error message.

Thanks for help.   I know this question has been asked before, but the previous answers did not help me.
Please help in baby steps, I am still overwhelmed by Windows programming.

Comment: Does `_eachWindow` call GetClassName? Then you need to link `user32.lib`. Check the `additional dependencies` in the project's linker settings, not the `additional library directories`.

Comment: dxiv's comment (2) makes the application work.  Thank you.
One of these days I might understand what the difference is, but for the moment I'm happy as is.

Comment: @dxiv, please post your comment as an answer, so the OP can accept it and close the question

Comment: @user3629249 That wasn't worthy of an answer, just asking for clarification. If the OP fills-in the missing context, posts an own answer, and accepts it, then I'll +1 that on top of the question being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Does `_eachWindow` call GetClassName? Then you need to link `user32.lib`. Check the `additional dependencies` in the project's linker settings, not the `additional library directories`.
                    – dxiv

dxiv's comment … makes the application work. – chris j